# Problemas con servlet

Tags: java, netbeans, servlets

Estoy intentando hacer unos servicios web para una app en Netbeans java y me lanza este error:

> GlassFish Server, deploy, Connection refused: connect, false
>   C:\Users\Win10\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1037:
>   The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details.
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 14 seconds)

Estoy usando Netbeans 11 y con el jee 8, lo he intentado con el jee 7 ya que me han dicho que puede ser ese el problema y nada..

Answer (score 1):

Edit---

Al ser con Glassfish puedes antes que nada probar con estos pasos.
Inicia NetBeans
Antes de hacer el despliegue mira que la ruta de tu Glassfish sea asi.

C:\Users\myusername\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\bin

Inicia asadmin.bat

Una vez se habra la consola: Inicia el dominio y vuelve a NetBeans, refresca hasta que veas es estado de running y ve al localhost a confirmarlo.

Para pararlo usa stop-domain.

---

En principio creo que el error es porque no especificas el servlet al proyecto y NetBeans falla al crear el fichero context.xml.

Si tu proyecto contiene la carpeta Web Pages, crea una carpeta META-INF.
Hazlo haciendo click en Web pages, y selecciona New->Other->Other->File Folder.

Llama al fichero META-INF.

Dentro crea un context.xml haciendo el mismo proceso de New->Other->XML->XML Document.

Llamalo context (NetBeans añade el .xml).

Edita el documento y añade:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/app-name"/>
```

Sustituye app-name por el nombre de tu aplicación/proyecto.

En teoria deberia funcionar, asegurate de que el fichero se pueda leer para todos.

context.xml es especifico para Tomcat si necesitas mas informacion miralo en tomcat.apache.org.

En caso de no funcionar puedes probar haciendo un pequeño reinicio de NetBeans.

Ve a 'Task Manager'
Elije el tab de 'Procesos'
Click en 'Java(TM) Platform SE Binary'
Click en 'Terminar proceso'
Ve a tu proyecto de Netbeans
Haz un Clean & Build al proyecto

En otros casos prueba a ejecutarlo como administrador.

Ojala te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. He conseguido solucionarlo. El problema era que como lo había hecho con Java EE Web 7 el glassfish tiene que ser del 4 para abajo. El glassfish 5 solo funciona con Java EE web 8. Lo que hice fue meterle el glassfish 4 y ya me funcionó.  Muchas gracias igualmente.

Comment: Entonces el clásico problema de versiones, me alegra que lo hayas solucionado.